# How to set percentage in Javascript for my progress bar?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I do not know anything in Javascript (I have copied a code for a progress bar but it does not display the percentage). I just need to display the text value of the actual % inside my progress bar (a text such as : 1%, 2%, 3%...).

The existing code I have is the following (I do not care about the style, so I removed it to read the code easier) :

```
<div id="loading">
<div id="progressbar">
<div id="progress"/>

<script>
 var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
 var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
 var progressbar = document.getElementById('progressbar');

 function updateProgress() 
 {
   if (loading.style.display !== 'none')
   {
       var width = parseInt(progress.offsetWidth + ((progressbar.offsetWidth - progress.offsetWidth) * .15));

       if (width > (progressbar.offsetWidth * .95))
        width = parseInt(progressbar.offsetWidth) * .5;

       progress.style.width = width + 'px';
       window.setTimeout("updateProgress()", 1000);
    }
  }
 document.body.style.margin = 0;
 document.body.style.padding = 0;
 loading.style.display = 'block';
 updateProgress();
 </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you help me to add the missing code to display a text having the percentage already loaded please ?

Comment: I forgot : a solution without JQUERRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML -- this is the element property to set the content of an element.

Assuming your progress percentage is defined as `var percent`, you'll just need to set the content as such:

```
progress.innerHTML = percent.toFixed(1) + '%';
```

Comment: Thanks you Travis, but, I thing there is a little of code missing...I have tried to add :

<div id=percent/> 
var percent= document.getElementById('percent');
progress.innerHTML = percent.toFixed(1) + '%';

Is that all ? I think it does not work...(I really do not understand Javascript)

Comment: Here's a fully working example without using any jQuery (although it's set to load, I'm not using it): http://jsfiddle.net/xYDhF/

Comment: Do you know with Chrome Inspector says : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'toFixed'

Comment: My example doesn't have that error, but if you see that, it means the object on which you're invoking toFixed is not a number, but a DIV html element instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, you may try **[Query Loader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/)**.

This preloader has it all. Loading bar, custom animations and getting all images included in the web page.

You can see a demo **[here](http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader/)**