# Percentage bar not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, percentage

I recently started adding a percentage bar to my posts on Blogger but when I use it, it always changes the percentage. I'm not sure why but here is one of my posts with it. if you reload it you will see a change in the percentage bar. http://www.honestreviews123.com/2018...bank-1010.html

Comment: here is the javascript code I used. i also used html and css but i think the problem is with the java. I would just like to take the animation out so the percentages will always be the same. thanks!

$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
var progress = $(this);
var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage
$({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
duration: 2000,
easing:'linear',
step: function() {

Comment: // What todo on every count
var pct = '';
if(percentage == 0){
pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
}else{
pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
}
progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
}
});
});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set percentage in Javascript for my progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588846/how-to-set-percentage-in-javascript-for-my-progress-bar)